# Permutation with repetition in Java (Strings are of the form: 00001112222)

Tags: java

I have strings of the form `000011122222`. That is, consecutive digits repeated random no. of times. Some other examples could be:

```
0011122223333
01222    
00011234444
001122222
```

and so on. I know, say for a string `01222`, that a total of `5!/3!` permutations are possible. I need to generate all these permutations for each such string.

I have tried generating permutations by various methods. One is by generating all the possible permutations (just as for strings without repetition), but since the strings that I would be using can be very large this can waste time generating too many redundant permutations.

Secondly, I have tried placing the digits at random indices of a character array equal to the size of the string and terminating the loop when the count of digits is same as in the input string. However, this way I am wasting a lot of memory and also taking up a lot of time.

I need an efficient way to generate permutations for such strings. Just an algorithm or code, either is welcome. I am using Java.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the input for the algorithm? The max length of the string? The number of different integers in the resulting strings?

Comment: @SimeonVisser: This problem is just a subpart of the thing i am coding. However, i have the the length of the string and also the consecutive integers which are repeated.

Comment: @Ganga: Sorry to ask. But i am new and dont know how to move the question to Computational Science.

Comment: @shrey347 "flag" it and ask for it to be moved, a moderator will take care of it.

Comment: Why was this migrated after an answer was given and accepted?  I think it is a better fit for Stackoverflow (as demonstrated by the fact that it received a good answer there).

Comment: @DavidKetcheson - Looks like user Ganga recommended that it be migrated for a high-quality answer and shrey347 requested migration as a result.  I agree that this particular question was probably better left at SO.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One of the standard algorithms for generating permutations is [an algorithm for listing them in lexicographically increasing order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Generation_in_lexicographic_order).  This algorithm, which is used by most implementations of the C++ `std::next_permutation` algorithm, generates permutations in at most O(n) time per permutation and skips over all permutations that are duplicates of one another.  It's also extremely easy to code up.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! I implemented the algorithm and it works perfectly well.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of permuting the original string of digits, permute the digit groups. I don't know how best to describe it so I'll try some psuedocode.

For the string "001222" the digit groups are two 0s, one 1, and three 2s.

```
permute(groups, permutation):
    if there are no non-empty groups
        print permutation
    else
        for each non-empty group
            permutation += group.digit
            --group.count
            permute(groups, permutation)
```

By looping over groups rather than all digits, it avoids generating duplicates because each digit can be chosen only once for the next position rather than multiple times. Walking through a random permutation you get

```
Permutation  Digit Groups

             0: 2, 1: 1, 2: 3  // start
0            0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 3
02           0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 2  // *
021          0: 1, 1: 0, 2: 2  // the 1 group is removed from the set
0212         0: 1, 1: 0, 2: 1
02120        0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 1  // the 0 group is removed from the set
021202       0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0  // the 2 group is removed from the set
```

Now unroll back to *.

```
02           0: 1, 1: 0, 2: 1
```

Because you are looping over digit groups rather than all the (repeated) digits from the original string, you cannot choose 2 again. This means all the permutations beginning with "02" will be unique because the prefix "02" is generated only once. The same applies throughout the algorithm.

**Update**

Here's a quick PHP implementation which produces 60 permutations for the input "001222":

```
function permute(&$groups, &$count, $permutation) {
    $done = true;
    foreach ($groups as &$group) {
        if ($group[1] > 0) {
            --$group[1];
            permute($groups, $count, $permutation . $group[0]);
            ++$group[1];
            $done = false;
        }
    }       
    if ($done) {
        echo $permutation . PHP_EOL;
        ++$count;
    }
}

$groups = array(
    array(0, 2),
    array(1, 1),
    array(2, 3),
);
$count = 0;
permute($groups, $count, '');
echo "\nTotal: $count\n";
```

Comment: I wish i could mark more than one answers as correct. I find this good but sorry i didnt try implementing this.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the strings by randomly choosing the count of digits. Like this:

```
length : int - Total string length
digits : int - maximum digit to include in the string
string : String - the return value
for(i : int from 0 to digits)
{
    remainingChars : int = length - length(string) //remaining chars in string
    remainingDigits : int = digits - i + 1
    count : int = Random from 1 to (remainingChars - remainingDigits + 1)
    Append count times i to the string
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i don't know exactly what you're trying to say, but i once needed a version of permutation where i had a set of numbers like 012 and all the permutations were:

012 021 102 120 201 210

in order to achieve this, i looked up on wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation
to find the algorithm, then i just created a method for it like this:

```
    public static boolean Permute(int[] a) {
        int k, l, n = a.length -1;
        for (k = n -1; ; k--) {
            if (k == -1)
                return false;
            if (a[k] < a[k + 1])
                break;
        }
        for (l = n; l >= 0; l--) {
            if (a[k] < a[l]) {
                int opt = a[l];
                a[l] = a[k];
                a[k] = opt;
                break;
            }
        }
        for (int i = k + 1, j = n; i < j; i++, j--) {
            int opt = a[i];
            a[i] = a[j];
            a[j] = opt;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

I can help you if you're more specific